# Are higher Sectors snow planets cooler?

Tags: starbound

> **Note:** Sectors was a beta feature and is **not available** in the stable 1.0 version of Starbound. Instead, different types of planets have hazards that correspond to the type of star they revolve around, and the hazards are mitigated through the use of an EPP (Environmental Protection Pack), not armor.

I am now on my first gamma sector snow planet and now i need warmer clothes, so i dont freeze to death. I was on a snow planet in beta sectors before and did not need my warm clothes. So do snow planets get colder with higher tier sectors or was it a illusion somehow?

Comment: Possibly it was not a cold planet, but rather a cold moon?  Moons are significantly colder than planets are, and if the moon happens to also be an arctic moon, it might stack coldness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the armours give cold protection, while others don't, or give less. I ran into this same thing, so I suspect you did what I did, and upgraded to an armour that gives less cold protection

Comment: i really dont think so, because i always built the human standard armor of the respective tier. which upgrade would lead into less cold protection ?

Comment: I believe Platinum armour may have provided lower cold protection. You could pull up the game and check. I'd do it myself, but some recent update wiped out my ship and everything in it :(